# Can an Android layout scale to fill the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

So I have an Android forms-based app that fills a 7" screen beautifully, portrait only, and there are over 50 forms. Rather than have to redesign each form (or the entire app) to suit each different resolution, my business case solution is to just scale the form to fill the screen. A 10" tablet will look a bit spaced out (but I can add some margins), and on a phone you better have a stylus and good eyesight!

Rather than argue about whether these are good choices, my question is: can it be done? On Windows CE the forms scale with the text size via "dialog box units", which works quite well. Android doesn't have anything like that, unless there are tricky ways of using 'sp' units. Regardless, getting a form to fill a screen nicely on different resolutions looks like hair-pulling-out territory, unless I'm missing something.

In answer to comments, it's a native app defined using XML layouts. For an example, you could take just about any sample app and show how to make it scale to different screen sizes, so you if the screen is small you get tiny text regardless of resolution.

Just to be clear: I don't think this question can be helpfully answered by describing how to use the standard Android way of handling multiple screen sizes: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. This is what I don't want to do this time. This really is about how to do other thing -- scaling to fit -- for when you really need it.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, yes, it can be done. But it would be better for you to put here some code and pictures of the forms.

Comment: @gnclmorais: yes, I agree but I haven't figured out how to do that usefully. Just take any native app and make it scale!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your situation well:

If it is a web application (you are using a webview) then use the viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;">
```

This will fit the page content to the device screen.

Or if it is a native application (also would work for a web application), you can add fill-parent for your layout heigth and width, in your layout [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
width = display.getWidth();
height = display.getHeight();
```

To get the height and width of any Android screen, and with this particular dimension, set the proportion for your layouts.

For example,

```
RelativeLayout fieldMain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.field_layout);

fieldMain.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((Int)(0.8*width), (int) (0.9*height)));
```